# Double integrate with sipy

Tags: python-3.x, math, scipy, calculation, integral

I want ask how can calculate this integral with python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVxR8.png)

```
    from scipy import integrate
    Hight_above_ground = 2.5 
    surface_ground = 81 
    surface_collector = 65 
    f = (np.cos(tilt)*np.cos(tilt)) / (PI * s **2 )
   (1/surface_ground) * integrate.dblquad(f, 0, surface_ground, 0, surface_collector)
```

NB : A1 and A2 are 2 surface areas A1 is surface_gound and A2 is surface_collector

and this the error given

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bifacial_systems.py", line 34, in <module>
    (1/surface_ground)*integrate.dblquad(f, 0, surface_ground, 0, surface_collector)
  File "C:\Users\S1-DEV-Manel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 602, in dblquad
    opts={"epsabs": epsabs, "epsrel": epsrel})
  File "C:\Users\S1-DEV-Manel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 826, in nquad
    return _NQuad(func, ranges, opts, full_output).integrate(*args)
  File "C:\Users\S1-DEV-Manel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 881, in integrate
    **opt)
  File "C:\Users\S1-DEV-Manel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 352, in quad
    points)
  File "C:\Users\S1-DEV-Manel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
  File "C:\Users\S1-DEV-Manel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 881, in integrate
    **opt)
  File "C:\Users\S1-DEV-Manel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 352, in quad
    points)
  File "C:\Users\S1-DEV-Manel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
ValueError: invalid callable given
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to check the docs and according examples first. May I ask what your knowledge level of Python is?

Comment: I am beginner and I want calculate double integral with python

Comment: So, if you check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html) you'll see that `f` needs to be a callable. This is what the error returns: "ValueError: invalid callable given" You need to make `f` a function that takes `y` and `x` ( careful about the order) and returns a function value. The examples do it with lambda functions but you can make a normal function definition. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) if you need examples.

Comment: yes I understand this , but in my function as you can see in image attached in my question there is no x and y I mean no unknown values

Comment: Well, I assume that thew angles theta are a function f the position in the area. Apart from this, the `quad` requires a callable, whether or not id actually depends on it. As an example take a constant function `f=1`. You'd still need to put `lambda f y, x: 1`

Comment: BTW what is theta_1,2?

Comment: theta1 and theta 2 are two angles

Comment: Sure they are, but if they would not depend on A_1 or A2, the integral would be pointless, i.e. over a constant, right?

Comment: yes I read more about they are variable all arround surface ( it is about the angle between the normal and the ray on solar panel)

Comment: so dA is like dx dy and cos theta is like cos theta( x, y ). So at the end this is probably a 4-dimensional integral, right?

Comment: yes we can consider it as a 4-dimensional integral

Comment: well, then you need `scipy.integrate.nquad` and write your callable accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite your integrand making expressing expressiong `dA1` and `dA2` in terms of `theta1`, `theta2`, `d theta1` and `d theta2`. Assuming that `dA1 dA2 = d theta1 d theta2` the solution would be

```py
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

def integrand(theta1, theta2, S):
    return np.cos(theta1)*np.cos(theta2)/S**2
S = 1

dblquad(integrand, 0, np.pi/2, 0, lambda x: np.pi/2-x, args=(S,))
```

In case you end up with an integral of higher order you can use [nquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html)